# How to read password protected Excel files using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel, xls

When Tried to read a password protected file using PHPExcel,I got this error.I tried pasting the password in different function of PHPExcel,but didn't work.Please tell me how to open password protected Excel file via PHPExcel.

```
There was a problem handling your file. Technical details: Cannot read encrypted file
```

My Code

```
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../uploads/' . $model->report);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    if ($inputFileType != 'CSV') {
         $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    }
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../uploads/' . $model->report);
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```

Comment: @MarkBaker, the developer responsible for PHPExcel stated one year ago that [PHPExcel does not support password-protected workbooks.](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/391284). Don't know if there's any news regarding this subject, but hopefully he's an active member here at SO and he'll clarify this shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, PHPExcel still can't read files that have been password protected, but somebody actually posted a PR yesterday that should allow this, based on the Perl encrypted file reader. I've yet to look at it, and doubt if I'll get much chance today due to real-world pressures of work; but I should get an opportunity to test it over the coming week... so there's real hope that the next release will allow reading of password protected xls files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Best of luck for the implementation of this feature.

Comment: Why not take a look at the 1.8.0 release and see for yourself?

Comment: @MarkBaker I have searched for the same, but only creating password protected excel file is available. I could not find how to read password protected file. Can you please help if you have any reference for the same. Thank you.